# How to remove body.onload when we click a link

Tags: javascript, html

I want to do a browser redirect using this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href = "mypage.html";
    }, 20000);
}
</script>
```

But I want to give user a way to stop the onload when click stop link, below is my code:

(`<a href="javascript:void()" style="text-decoration:underline; color:#FFFF00" onclick="window.onload()=null" id="stop"> stop </a>`)

but, onload function still not stopped, I am just a beginner student in javascript, plz help me how to stop onload function when we click stop

Comment: `setTimeout` returns a value that you can use to cancel the timer.

Comment: you can use `clearTimeout` to stop the redirect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To unset the event handler, you have to assign null to window.onload

```
window.onload = null;
```

However, this will not fix your problem as you have started a timer at that point. That's what you need to remove.
Firstly, store a reference to your timeout in a variable:

```
var redirectTimeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = "mypage.html";
}, 20000);
```

And then use clearTimeout to stop the timer:

```
window.clearTimeout(redirectTimeout);
```